# Why are ARM Cortex-R parts so rare?

Tags: arm, cortex

Most every ARM licensee under the sun sells dozens of Cortex-A and Cortex-M parts, but as far as I can tell, only TI, Renesas, and Cypress (oops, Infineon) sell Cortex-R parts. Of those three, TI is the only one that seems serious about it. (Renesas has like three products and none of them implement dual-core lockstep for some reason.)

It seems like Cortex-R has a lot to recommend it for safety-critical applications. I'd expect to see it used in a lot of parts targeting automotive applications, but those seem to be Cortex-A, Cortex-M, or some non-ARM architecture.

Comment: Interestingly, some SoC FPGAs offer a mix of Cortex-A and Cortex-R cores, like the [Zynq Ultrascale+](https://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/soc/zynq-ultrascale-mpsoc.html) I'm currently working with.

Comment: The Cortex-R just recently got support (on some units) for an MMU, so these tend to be pretty specialized devices that are integrated into larger systems.  As a stand-alone part there isn't a lot of demand for relatively high performance CPUs that also don't support virtual memory and so cannot run typical operating systems.  For devices where OS support is not important, usually you don't need superscalar execution and multiple GHz clocks, you just use a microcontroller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Cortex-R parts are only really used in systems that need some sort of "reliability guarantee".  As such, the market is much more limited than general Cortex parts--generally only automotive, aerospace, and medical find the extra expense worth it.  And even then only in *very* limited contexts.  Automotive, for example, is so price sensitive that they won't be willing to pay the premium for such a part unless they're actually *forced* to do so.